# Running rails + postgres in kubernetes: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, kubernetes

My rails deployment is not able to connect to the postgres database. Error in the logs:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "db" (10.0.105.11) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):
```

This is my `kubectl get services` output:

```
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
load-balancer            LoadBalancer   10.0.5.147     60.86.4.33    80:31259/TCP   10m
db                       ClusterIP      10.0.105.11    <none>        5432/TCP       10m
kubernetes               ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        10m
web                      ClusterIP      10.0.204.107   <none>        3000/TCP       10m
```

db-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: postgres
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD
          value: trust
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: PGDATA
          value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        image: postgres
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: db
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: postgres
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres
status: {}
```

db-service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db
  labels:
    app: db
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    app: db
    tier: database
```

config/database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  host: db
  username: postgres
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

How do I ensure the postgres instance is running and accepting connections? Did I misconfigure something in the manifest files, or does the database.yml file need to point to a different host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that your `db` service is targeting two selectors `app: db` and `tier: database`, however the corresponding `deployment.yml` only has the `db` label.  You will need to add the `tier` label to your deployment template metadata so that the service will appropriately target the right pod.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db
    tier: database 
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: db
        tier: database
```

In general, if a service is not connecting to a backend pod, you can easily diagnose the issue with a simple kubectl command.
This will tell you what current selectors are applied to your service

```
kubectl describe service db -o yaml
```

Then you can fetch the pods that the selectors refer to and make sure that this is returning something.

```
kubectl get pods -l app=db -l tier=database
```

Finally, I would recommend using the *DNS* name of the service setup through kube-proxy instead of the cluster IP address. I tend to view this as more resilient then a cluster up, as it will be automatically routed if the services IP ever changes. In your connection string use `db:5432` instead of `10.0.105.11`.

Comment: That works, thank you very much for the suggestion!